# template template parameter deduction with C++ class templates

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way, without partial template specialization, to determine the template parameter of a template parameter that a class is templatized with, assuming that a class can only be templatized with a template parameter that itself is a template?

To make things concrete, here's an example:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct A {
// Needed: a function to print the size of the template parameter
// that "T" is templatized with, e.g. "char" in the example
// below
};

template <typename A>
struct X{}

int main() {
  A<X<char>>
}
```

Comment: So you want to pattern match... but cut out the pattern matching mechanism... why!?

Comment: I know it doesn't answer the question itself ("is there a way..."), but depending on what you're trying to achieve, here's an idea: you don't have to partially specialize your class itself, but rather create a separate partially specialized helper class and pretend it's a standard library function (e.g. part of type_traits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is for situations like this why standard containers expose a `value_type` member, eg:

```
template <class T>
struct A {
    // Needed: a function to print the size of the template parameter
    // that "T" is templatized with, e.g. "char" in the example
    // below
    void printSize() const { cout << sizeof(typename T::value_type); }
};

template <typename A>
struct X {
    using value_type = A;
};
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/vDakX9)

Otherwise, you can use a separate helper that utilizes a **template template parameter** and **template argument deduction** to determine what the value type is, eg:

```
template<template<class, class...> class C, class T, class... OtherTs>
size_t A_helper_printSize(C<T, OtherTs...>&&) { return sizeof(T); }

template <class T>
struct A {
    // Needed: a function to print the size of the template parameter
    // that "T" is templatized with, e.g. "char" in the example
    // below
    void printSize() const { cout << A_helper_printSize(T{}); }
};
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/OnwEoQ)

Alternatively:

```
template<template<class, class...> class C, class T, class... OtherTs>
T A_helper_valueType(C<T, OtherTs...>&&);

template <class T>
struct A {
    // Needed: a function to print the size of the template parameter
    // that "T" is templatized with, e.g. "char" in the example
    // below
    void printSize() const { cout << sizeof(decltype(A_helper_valueType(std::declval<T>()))); }
};
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/rqqBWe)

Comment: Nice one with the template function. I think it may be improved a bit though - to avoid T instantiation (when T is not default-constructible, for example). If helper function implementation is removed and it's return type is changed to T, you can easily extract size of T with `sizeof(decltype(A_helper_sizeOfT(std::declval<T>())))`.

Comment: @Dmitry thanks, I have incorporated it into my answer.  I knew there was a way to do it, but I've never been good with using `declval`